# Antd Alert message, description and icon not showing up in react app

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

I have a react app that uses antd ui components. I am trying to use the Alert component. However, I am not able to get the alert component to display the message or icon. The only thing the alert is displaying is the closable icon and the action elements.

```js
    <Alert message={"Success"}
           description={"Success description"}
           type="success"
           showIcon
           closable={true}
           action={
               <Button size="small" type="text">
                   OK
               </Button>
           }
    />
```

The above Alert component only shows the **OK** button that is defined for the action property and the closeable icon.

Comment: This looks fine to me, i think you should check your text-color CSS. I can help if you can provide a codesandbox URL here. But whatever you have written works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shivamragnar
 Although it was not exactly related to the text color, but it definitely was css related. I figured out that in the past I had myself disabled the icon and message selectors of original Alert component(which was definitely a bad idea in the first place) inorder to customise the Alert component for a specific requirement. I got this fixed by disabling the more specific selectors instead of the generic Alert. My earlier custom alert components too work fine now and I am also able to use the original anyd Alert component without any issues.

Comment: That's great to hear. Kudos!!